# How can I disable a python program from logging (externally)?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

There is a [python program](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_generation.py) that I want to run without modification, but I want to stifle logging. However, the program doesn't expose access to logging settings via command line arguments. Is there any way to get rid of logging output but retain the normal output of the program when I run the file?

The best solution I can think of is to wrap the file in another file that disables logging, but I'd like to stifle logging output directly when running the file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

import logging
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)

Comment: I'm looking for way to stifle logging externally, when I run the program from the command line